# Use global type instead of the local subtype with same name

Tags: oracle, types, plsql, package, subtype

I have a oracle database with several packages and some types. There is a type defined like

```
create or replace type my_type as table of varchar2(4000)
```

And then, into `pkg_machines` there is

```
subtype my_type is varchar2(4000)
```

Now, I didn't write the database and while analyzing errors I discovered that several packages do use `pkg_machines.my_type`, but `pkg_machines` needs to use both the local and the global one.

The only possible way that came in my mind to do this, is to change the name of the subtype and refactorize every other package that uses it, but it would mean to waste a lot of time on refactoring hundreds of packages.

My question is: is there a way to tell to a procedure to refer to the global type `my_type` instead of the defined subtype?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use the global name fully qualify it as `schema_name.my_type`. The schema name will usually be the same as the user you were logged in to the database with when the type was created.

Share and enjoy.